# Skip target for missing files

Tags: makefile

I am trying to create a Makefile which skips a target if the input file is missing. At the moment I am using the following code:

```
default:    foo \
            bar

foo:    foo.pdf
bar:    bar.pdf

%.pdf: %.tex
    @if [ -s $< ]; then \
        pdflatex -interaction=batchmode $<; \
    else \
        echo 'Skipped' $<; \
    fi;
```

It works as long as the file `foo.tex` exists, but fails if it is missing:

> make: *** No rule to make target 'foo.pdf', needed by 'foo'.  Stop.

Instead of stopping I would like the process to continue with `bar.tex` which may exists.

How to handle such cases properly?

Comment: Would `make -k` suffice?

Comment: @G.M. This could be an option, but ideally there would be a solution where I do not have to keep in mind to pass an additional parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
%.pdf: %.tex
    pdflatex -interaction=batchmode $<

%.pdf:
    @echo Skipped $@
```

Comment: This does not throw the target error anymore, but stops with a "File not found" error for `foo.pdf`.

Comment: @epR8GaYuh: That is not a Make error message, at least not in 3.8.1. Is there any more to the output than that?

Comment: `process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, echo Skipped foo.pdf. ...) failed. make (e = 2): The system cannot find the file specified. make: *** [foo.pdf] Error 2` on Windows.

Comment: @epR8GaYuh: I can't reproduce the error. It seems to be a complaint about the `echo` command; all I can suggest is that you try a few variations of it, such as `echo "skipped $@"`

Comment: Wrapping at least the string (`@echo "Skipped" $@`) seems to fix the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the basic idea of using `make -k` is acceptable then the easiest way to invoke it without having to explicitly specify the `-k` flag might be to simply have a `makefile` that bootstraps itself to add that option.

```
ifneq ($(origin bootstrapped),undefined)
default:    foo \
            bar

foo:    foo.pdf
bar:    bar.pdf

%.pdf: %.tex
    @if [ -s $< ]; then \
        pdflatex -interaction=batchmode $<; \
    else \
        echo 'Skipped' $<; \
    fi;
else

# If the variable `boostrapped' is undefined then we simply run
# the same make invocation but with added -k and bootstrapped=1
default:
    $(MAKE) bootstrapped=1 $(MAKEFLAGS) -k -f $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))
endif
```

Cheap and cheerful -- but it should work.

Comment: This throws an error for me: `make: option requires an argument -- f`

Comment: Which version of `make` are you using?  Can you show the output of `make -v`?

Comment: It did not work with version 3.80, upgrading to 3.81 works fine.